# Use GitHub Package R Actions

Tags: r, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I was trying to use [actions](https://github.com/features/actions) in a [package](https://github.com/Nelson-Gon/manymodelr) I wrote. The issue is that the package [actions](https://github.com/r-lib/actions) uses `remotes` in its setup to install CRAN only packages.

Since the package I am working on depends on a non CRAN package that is present on GitHub, both coverage and R CMD checks fail. I tried to avoid this by naively downgrading to an earlier version of the package in depends but some functions are not exported. I am wondering if someone knows a workaround that might help(I cannot open an issue at actions since their `support.md` file discourages this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time, I have found a workaround that for now is good enough if you want to test for the development version(like I wanted). You should include an `install_github` command in the `check.yaml` file. Here's an example:

```
 - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          install.packages(c("remotes","testthat"),dependencies=TRUE)
          remotes::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")
          remotes::install_cran("covr")
        shell: Rscript {0}
```

The above snippet fixed my issue because I wanted to depend on a future `dplyr` version. You can view the full `yaml` file [here](https://github.com/Nelson-Gon/mde/blob/master/.github/workflows/devel-check.yaml).

Answer (score 2):

If your package depends on a non-CRAN package, you must include under `Remotes:` rather than just `Imports:` in your DESCRIPTION file. Here you would have:

```r
Imports:
  actions
Remotes:
  r-lib/actions
```

This will pass checks, but there is no work around for publishing to CRAN if any of your dependencies are not on CRAN, thus you'll get a warning if any packages are present in the `Remotes` field.

The alternative using Travis is adding `r_github_packages: r-lib/actions` to your .travis.yml.

Comment: This is good.I guess I'll try this for now, I hoped there was something like Travis' where I just include some line in the yaml file.

Comment: Added solution using Travis.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding. I'm trying to avoid Travis(I already have this in Travis but need something similar for the yaml file that runs actions on GitHub)