# github action cannot find the files of my R package

Tags: r, github-actions, r-package

I am trying to get Github Action to check my package. The packages compiles fine (not even a note) on my computer. I created a yaml script to go into the github workflow directory using `usethis::use_github_action_check_standard()` but it fails with a bunch of warnings like

> No files were found with the provided path: check. No artifacts will
> be uploaded.

The path check is a temporary directory created by  `rcmdcheck` for storing files. So, I presume it is a problem connected with this command. But everything was created by the usethis utility and nobody else seems to have the same problem.

[image]

I looked around a lot and the last fix I tried was to manually add a step to install imported and suggested packages, as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61405539/use-github-package-r-actions), to no avail.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

the yaml script is

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

name: R-CMD-check

jobs:
  R-CMD-check:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.config.os }}

name: ${{ matrix.config.os }} (${{ matrix.config.r }})

strategy:
  fail-fast: false
  matrix:
    config:
      - {os: windows-latest, r: 'release'}
      - {os: macOS-latest, r: 'release'}
      - {os: ubuntu-20.04, r: 'release', rspm: "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/__linux__/focal/latest"}
      - {os: ubuntu-20.04, r: 'devel', rspm: "https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/__linux__/focal/latest"}

env:
  R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS: true
  RSPM: ${{ matrix.config.rspm }}
  GITHUB_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v1
    with:
      r-version: ${{ matrix.config.r }}

  - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-pandoc@v1

  - name: Install dependencies
    run: |
      install.packages(c("geigen","stringr", "leaps", "stats"),dependencies=TRUE)
      install.packages(c("elasticnet","glmnet"),dependencies=TRUE)
    shell: Rscript {0}


  - name: Query dependencies
    run: |
      install.packages('remotes')
      saveRDS(remotes::dev_package_deps(dependencies = TRUE), ".github/depends.Rds", version = 2)
      writeLines(sprintf("R-%i.%i", getRversion()$major, getRversion()$minor), ".github/R-version")
    shell: Rscript {0}

  - name: Cache R packages
    if: runner.os != 'Windows'
    uses: actions/cache@v2
    with:
      path: ${{ env.R_LIBS_USER }}
      key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('.github/R-version') }}-1-${{ hashFiles('.github/depends.Rds') }}
      restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('.github/R-version') }}-1-

  - name: Install system dependencies
    if: runner.os == 'Linux'
    run: |
      while read -r cmd
      do
        eval sudo $cmd
      done < <(Rscript -e 'writeLines(remotes::system_requirements("ubuntu", "20.04"))')

  - name: Install dependencies
    run: |
      remotes::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE)
      remotes::install_cran("rcmdcheck")
    shell: Rscript {0}

  - name: Check
    env:
      _R_CHECK_CRAN_INCOMING_REMOTE_: false
    run: |
      options(crayon.enabled = TRUE)
      rcmdcheck::rcmdcheck(args = c("--no-manual", "--as-cran"), error_on = "warning", check_dir = "check")
    shell: Rscript {0}

  - name: Upload check results
    if: failure()
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@main
    with:
      name: ${{ runner.os }}-r${{ matrix.config.r }}-results
      path: check
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by moving everything to the main branch.

Comment: what do you men with "moving everything to the main brach"; did you have a lot of other branches that you removed?